# Remove blue border from printed link images in IE8

Tags: html, css, printing, internet-explorer-8

I've already read through the similar questions on this topic, but none of them address the problem associated with printing.

I have dynamically generated images that are links as well. Using the following CSS, I am able to prevent blue borders from displaying on the link images in Firefox and IE8.

```
a img { border: 0; }
```

However, when printing the page from IE8, the blue border persists. I can't find any options in IE8 to prevent this behavior, and I've already taken action via CSS. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent the annoying blue borders from printing?

Comment: Have you checked the media type for your stylesheet ?

Comment: OK, I feel really stupid now. I was editing the screen media sheet instead of the printer media sheet. Using the exact CSS from my original question in the printer media worked perfectly.

Comment: We all do it sometimes, glad the prompt helped

Comment: Not a bad question, I forgot that you can even make a separate style sheet for printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big derp moment for me.

Using:

```
a img { border: 0; }
```

in media="print" sheet worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `a { outline: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reset more than just links, Reset code = http://CSSesta.tk

Below will fix a few other issues if you haven't already dealt with them.

*If it's an actual styling border rather than an outline `a img { border: 0; }` may help though you may need to track down the styling that its causing it (**in that scenario**)*

```
/**/
a:hover,a:active{
    outline: none;
}
body div:focus{
    outline: none;
}
img{
    outline:none;
}
a:focus{
    outline:none;
}
a::-moz-focus-inner{
    border: 0;
}
```